# UIDatePicker view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

How to pass time from `NSString` in `UIDatePickerView`

Comment: What are you asking? Try rephrasing your question to be more specific.

Comment: I want to know that how to set TIME i.e 8:00 AM in uidatepickerview when picker showing current date but time is 8:00 AM

Comment: NSDateFormater doens;t show any method setTimeFormat in iOS 5.0

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString * date = @"2010-12-10";
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd"];
    NSDate *anyDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:date];   
    [datePicker setDate:anyDate];

    [dateFormat release];
}
```

didn't test it, but should work.. or else point you in the right direction

edit for time:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString * time = @"08:00-am";
    [timeFormat setTimeFormat:@"hh':'mm'-'tt"];
    NSDate *anyTime = [timeFormat dateFromString:time];   
    [datePicker setTime:anyTime];

    [timeFormat release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to fix the TIME i.e 8:00 AM every time in uidatepickerview, date does not matter here.

Comment: OK. Use "setTimeFormat:@"hh':'mm-'tt"]; and datePicker setTime:time"